# Bash: Insert unescaped string/characters from variable into command

Tags: bash, shell, substitution

In bash (GNU bash, version 3.2.57), I would like to substitute the exact content of a variable (unescaped) into a following command.

To illustrate what I mean, given the following string variable:

```
s="2>&1 > /dev/null"
```

If I try to insert that exact string into a command:

```
bash --version $s || echo "will install bash"
```

(this command is just a simple example for the sake of the question)

The command actually executed looks like this:

```
bash --version '2>&1' '>' /dev/null
```

The inserted strings are escaped, which I don't want.

What I would like instead is to somehow insert the content of `s`, unescaped, into the executed command, so that the executed command is this one:

```
bash --version 2>&1 > /dev/null
```

How could I achieve that ?

Comment: Is this XY question? Don't you want instead to detect if bash installed?

Comment: Not really, I just chose a simple one-line example for the question, I do want to silence some commands, and in other cases conditionally pass flags to other commands. I tried to simplify the question, thinking the presence of redirections wouldn't make any difference.
It seems from the answers that it does make a difference.

Comment: and about this -1 vote, what should I improve about the question ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How could I achieve that ?

Instead of a variable, use a function.

```
run_this_silent() {
     "$@" 2>&1 >/dev/null
}
run_this_silent bash --version
```

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to store redirections in a variable without using `eval` (or the equivalent `bash -c COMMAND`), and [`eval` is a bad solution](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/048) in pretty much every case imaginable. If you want to unconditionally silence a command (or a hundred commands) it's better to explicitly add the redirects to each of them.

Comment: Do you have an example of what I shouldn't do and an explanation of why it's wrong ?